# React Routing - How to load pop up using Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popup, react-router-v4

What I have:
1. Login Component
[image: Login]
2. Register Component
[image: Register]

In Login Component, there is a link called register. It routes it to Register page. The code is simple:

```
<Link to='/register' className='links align-left'>Register</Link>
```

I want to show the register component in a popup instead. I know, I can use a Dialog Component and show the register component in that dialog. Easy, but what I don't understand is how I can set my routing so it shows the login window behind, and loads the registration component in the popup. Lemme explain with an example. See how trello board works in following screenshot. The url is **https://trello.com/b/i1QoQatf/**[image: Trello Board]

Now when I click an item, it shows me a pop up, like in following screenshot. Please note the URL right now is **https://trello.com/c/QisVDEgX/639-sort-all-dropdowns-alphaetically**

[image: Trello Pop up]

Now my confusion is, how can I achieve the same for my Login and Register component. If I load my routing like this:

```
<Route path='/register' component={RegisterComponent} />
```

It will call the render method of Register Component, and then only load the Register Component. How I can route it to Register Component, and still use Login in the background. Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding my solution here so people will understand the concept of routing.

This is actually pretty easy, if you are using NextJS. In NextJS, we need to use a server (like express) for routing. NextJS router is very strong and give loads of flexibility. Also, NextJS Link tag is as powerful. Following is the explanation on how to achieve the url routing without loading the page.

In general, you can reach to a page two ways. 1. By clicking a link/button (for example Register Now) 2. By pasting the URL directly in browser. Let's say, I have two URLs:

1. https://example.com/login
2. https://example.com/register

Now, what I want to achieve is, when I click the "Register Now" link in my Login page, it should route my page to /register but still show Login page in the background, and Registration form in popup. But remember, I want to achieve this by making sure the Login component doesn't load twice.

With NextJS, following will be the way to do it:

1. We will be creating one next js page called account.js
2. For routing to our login page, the link for login screen will be something like following:

```
    <Link href={{pathname: '/account', query: { mode: 'login' }}} as {'/login}>
    <a>Login</a>
    </Link>
```

The link page will route us to accounts page.

3. If you noticed, the link tag is not a normal href. The above link tag means, "we want to go to account page, but show url as "/login", and when we render account page, send query {mode: 'login'} to the account pages' router object.
4. In the render function of account page, we can make a decision in run time easily on the basis of router's query object.

```
      render() {
        const mode = this.props.router.query.mode;


        return (
          <div>
            <LoginComponent></LoginComponent>
            {/* the following line will open the register component in a popup */}
            {mode === 'registration' && <PopUp><RegisterComponent></RegisterComponent></PopUp>}
          </div>
        )

      }
```

5. In login component, we will add the registration link like following:

```
        <Link href={{pathname: '/account', query: { mode: 'registration' }}} as={`/`}>
          <a>Register Now</a>
        </Link>
```

In above example, all we did was created a page called accounts.js. We made sure that when we route to Login window, we route it to accounts page, but we send mode: 'login'. When we click on register link, we are loading the same page - accounts.js but with a different mode: 'registration'. The render function will open the register component in popup because mode is === 'registration'. In url, it will show the address as '/register'

Please note: That is just an example code for reference, It is by no means a tested code so please bear that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think to achieve this your RegisterComponent will have to render login component and a register popup.

Within your render function you will return where RegisterPopup is your registration form rendered in popup (let's assume react modal)

```
<React.Fragment>
    <LoginComponent/>
    <RegisterPopup/>
</React.Fragment>
```

Comment: It will certainly reload the LoginComponent, no? I guess I am unable to explain it correctly, but I need to replicate the pop up behavior, without any overhead using routing. Is this even possible?

Comment: There are two approaches I can think of, first you make register as subroute of login (/login/register) where login will render login component and if the subroute is register it will render your popup. Second make use of query params /login?register=true use this queryparam to conditionally render the register popup.

Comment: Thanks for the help Shubham, but using register with login doesn't make lot of sense from a user point of view. But at last, I was able to do it with NextJs. Thanks again.